How would this partial differential equation (PDE) be classified? Can it be solved for any integer $a>0$?
I am trying to find the Laplace transformation of a multivariable function that satisfies the following equation:
$$
ax(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_it_i^ax(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)}+u(a) 
\text{ where } a \in \mathbb{N}
$$
for an application in neuroscience. Rearranging this equation gives:
$$
x(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)=\frac{u(a)}{t-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_it_i^{a}}
$$
I am not able to find the Laplace transformation of the function from this second equation, but applying the Laplace transform to both sides of the original equation gives the following partial differential equation:
$$
aX(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_i\frac{\partial^a{X(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)}}{\partial{s_i}^a}}+\frac{u(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}s_i}
$$
where $s_i$ is the Laplace variable corresponding to the time variable $t_i$. I am a second-year engineering student, and my level of understanding is still limited to intermediate calculus and ordinary differential equations, although I am very willing to read independently to learn more.
This being said, I have very little experience with multivariable Laplace transformations, as well as with solving partial differential equations.
Would this be a linear inhomogeneous/nonhomogeneous $a$-th order PDE? Would it be possible to solve this PDE in general for any integer $a>0$? Could separation of variables be applied somehow to obtain the solution?

Has anybody  an idea why this gets closed?

Its an inhomogenous linear PDE of  order s, elliptic if all $\lambda_i>0$.
By rescaling the differential operator becomes spherical $\Delta^{(\times s)} \ = \ \sum_i \partial_i^s$ with the $(\times s)$ power meaning componentwise product and sum in the sense of Fourier transform $\mathcal F(-i \nabla f)(k) = k \ \mathcal F(f)(k) $
The inhomogenous term factorizes per coordinates, a product ansatz reduces the equation to the linear system of order s
$$\prod_i f_i(x_i)\  = \  \prod_i \partial_i^s f(x_i) \ + \  \prod_i \frac{1}{x_i}$$
$$x_i f_i(x_i)\  = \    \partial_i^s f_(x_i) \ + \ 1 + c_i, \quad \sum_i c_i=0$$
